# Query entre 3 tablas con MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta y añadirle los valores de dos tablas al resultado para así poder traer la inflacionario que necesito

las tablas `matches` y `blocked` se relacionan con `users` mediante los id's

El query que estoy tratando de realizar es el siguiente:

```
SELECT u.*, m.*
FROM users u, matches m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT idblock
FROM blocked b
WHERE b.idBlock = u.id AND b.idBlocked = 9) AND u.id <> 9
```

y el resultado lo trae como necesito pero lo repite muchas veces, lo intente realizar con un `where exists` pero no me dio resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la relación que tienen las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que trato de traer en mi consulta es toda la información del `id` y los campos `idMatch` y el `idMatched` siempre y cuando `accepted = 0` en la tabla de `matches` pero siempre y cuando el `id` de usuario no exista en `idBlocked`

> RELACIÓN ENTRE TABLAS

la tabla de `users` es la tabla primaria por consecuente

en la tabla `matches idMatch y idMatched` tienen una `FK` a `id` de la tabla `users` como se muestra en la imagen

y en la tabla de `blocked idBlock y idBlocked` tienen la `FK` a `id` de `users`

Ambas tablas tienen una relación de 1 a muchos

vuelvo a repetir la intención de mi consulta:

quiero traer toda la informacion de usuarios para mostrarla en pantalla pero quiero saber si ya se tiene un `match` para mostrar un botón, pero en caso de que no haya match mostrar otro botón pero también quiero saber si el id del usuario no se ha ingresado a la tabla de blocked

ej. si usuario 1 bloquea a usuario 3 no le aparecera en pantalla pero todos los demás si

Relacion de if's entre tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@A.Cedano como lo mencionas, las tablas de match y blocked son relaciones entre usuarios, realmente no se como explicarme en lo que quiero hacer.

pero en mi cabeza mi intención es tomar todos los registros de la tabla users después hacer una comparación en la tabla match es decir, si en la tabla match el usuario idMatch es = 9 y idMatched = 3 en la vista se mostrara un boton, de lo contrario se mostrara otro boton

despues quiero hacer otra comparacion donde un usuario no ha bloqueado a otro es decir si idBlock = 3 y idBlocked = 9, el usuario con el id 3 no se mostrara en pantalla para el usuario 9.

y para asi al final decir "ok, el resultado me trajo todos los usuarios de la tabla users pero id 9 tiene un match con el id 7, entonces mostrare este boton pero id 3 bloqueo al id 9, entonces no le mostrare este usuario"

Pero todo eso quiero hacerlo en una sola consulta para que pueda mostrar todos los resultados en pantalla

Comment: No veo qué hace ahí la tabla `matches`, con qué tabla se relaciona y mediante qué columna...

Comment: @A.Cedano ya actualice mi pregunta con tu duda, todas las tablas tienen relacion con users que es la principal

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir *las tablas matches y blocked se relacionan con users mediante los id's*... sé claro en tu explicación, ¿los id's?  ¿qué id's exactamente? porque en los resultados se nota claramente que los valores de `matches` andan de su cuenta. En la consulta no estás expresando la forma en que `matches` se relaciona con las otras tablas. En una consulta **debes expresar claramente quién se relaciona con quien y mediante qué columnas**, y también debes expresarlo en la exposición de la pregunta, por supuesto.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya actualice, espero haberme explicado de manera mas precisa

Comment: Yo lamentablemente no trabajo con esos diagramas, ni siquiera los entiendo a decir verdad. Hay unas flechas verdes que apuntan para un lado y para otro. Tú tienes que decirme: *la tabla `users` se relaciona con la tabla X mediante las columna X y la columna Y; la tabla Z  se relaciona con la tabla W mediante las columnas tal y tal*... Si te explicas así ya sabríamos el problema y tendríamos una solución, pero unos diagramas con flechas que no se saben bien para donde apuntan ni a qué columna apuntan, no explican nada.

Comment: *en la tabla matches idMatch y idMatched tienen una FK a id de la tabla users como se muestra en la imagen*  ¿O sea que tanto `idMatch` como `idMatched` se relacionan con la columna `id` de la tabla `users`? Si es así, posiblemente haya que hacer un doble `JOIN` con la tabla `users` o uno solo, depende de lo que quieras realmente. Cuando dices *pero quiero saber si ya se tiene un match para mostrar un botón*  ¿a cuál de las dos columnas te refieres, a `idMatch` o a `idMatches`? Siento insistir tanto, pero yo veo tu diseño confuso y sin explicar el contexto es difícil  entender la situación.

Comment: Si quieres te puedo ayudar con una respuesta pero necesito entender bien el problema desde el principio. ¿Qué hace cada tabla, para qué sirve y cómo se relaciona con las otras tablas y mediante qué columnas?  ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Si respondes a esas dos preguntas entonces podré proponerte una solución.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de agregar un poco mas de explicacion, espero eso sea de ayuda para darme a enteder en que es lo que quiero como resultado

Answer (score 3):

He tratado de reproducir tu problema basándome en datos reales y no he encontrado una forma óptima de obtener el resultado deseado.

Si he entendido bien, se trata de gestionar relaciones entre usuarios.

La tabla `matches` serviría para saber qué usuarios han solicitado amistad a qué usuarios. La columna `accepted` indicaría si la solicitud de amistad está aceptada  `1` o no aceptada `0`.

La tabla `blocked` serviría para indicar quién ha bloqueado a quién.

Hay varios problemas en ese diseño. Yo encontré una forma de obtener los resultados que querías, pero no era del todo satisfactoria por un sólo motivo: en la tabla `matches` el usuario puede participar digamos como *emisor*  o como *receptor*  de la solicitud de amistad. En ese caso, controlar que el usuario que buscamos esté como *emisor*  o como *receptor*  tumbó mi supuesta solución.

A mi me parece que tu diseño de datos se puede pensar mejor. Además, es posible que no tengas que manejar solamente los bloqueos. ¿Qué tal si tienes que manejar cosas como solicitudes pendientes? ¿Qué tal si necesitas saber quién bloqueó a quien o si se han bloqueado mutuamente?

Entonces propongo esta solución:  **crear en la tabla `matches` una columna que se encargará de gestionar todos los estados posibles de la relación**, a saber:

- *amigos* : ambos han aceptado la solicitud
- *emisor pendiente de receptor*: o sea, fulano le mandó solicitud de amistad a mengano, pero éste no ha respondido
- *receptor pendiente de emisor*: o sea, mengano le mandó solicitud a fulano, pero éste no ha respondido
- *fulano bloqueó a mengano*
- *mengano bloqueó a fulano*
- *se bloquearon mutuamente*: o sea, la relación de amistad terminó en tragedia ):

En tu diseño tú puedes implementar una *convención numérica*  (ver comentario antes del `CREATE TABLE` de ejemplo en la DEMO más abajo) que exprese cada estado de la relación o puedes usar `ENUM`... eso es lo de menos.

Haciéndolo así, mediante esta consulta obtendrás por ejemplo todos los amigos del usuario `1`:

```
SELECT 
    ue.user_id id_emisor, 
    ur.user_id id_receptor
FROM matches_20180713 m
    LEFT JOIN users_20180713 ue ON ue.user_id=m.match_emisor
    LEFT JOIN users_20180713 ur ON m.match_receptor=ur.user_id
WHERE 
    m.match_emisor=1 OR m.match_receptor=1 AND m.match_status=1;
```

El resultado sería algo así digamos:

```
id_emisor   id_receptor
    1            2
    4            1
```

Muestra que el ususario `1` es amigo de los usuarios `2` y `4`. Y muestra además que él le pidió amistad al `2` y que el `4` le pidió amistad a él. Claro. Suponte que te piden estadísticas en ese sentido, que te dice tu jefe: *a ver, quiero una consulta para saber, de los amigos de `1`, a cuántos le pidió él amistad y cuántos se la pidieron a él*. Con este diseño lo tienes totalmente resuelto.

Ahora, supongamos que quieres mostrar las situaciones de bloqueo del usuario `1`. Ejecutas esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
    ue.user_id id_emisor, 
    ur.user_id id_receptor,
    m.match_status
FROM matches_20180713 m
    LEFT JOIN users_20180713 ue ON ue.user_id=m.match_emisor
    LEFT JOIN users_20180713 ur ON m.match_receptor=ur.user_id
WHERE 
    (m.match_emisor=1 OR m.match_receptor=1) AND m.match_status>3;
```

En nuestra columna `match_status` he acordado previamente que los estados de bloqueo sean a partir del `4`, por eso el `WHERE ...  m.match_status>3`. La consulta arrojará datos así:

```
id_emisor   id_receptor      match_status
    5             1               4
    1             7               6
```

Podemos leer entonces que el usuario `5` le pidió amistad al usuario `1` y que luego lo bloquéo (es lo que representa el `4`  en nuestra convención numérica de estados).  Vemos también que el usuario `1` pidió amistad al usuario `7` en una época dorada pero que esa relación terminó en un bloqueo mutuo... se acabaron los años dorados :(

Esta es mi propuesta para la solución de este tan intrincado problema. Quizá haya soluciones mejores. Es cuestión de probar y quedarte con la que más te convenga.

> Si quieres hacer una prueba sobre los datos que he usado para
>   reproducir el problema, puedes ver esta <kbd>**[DEMO EN
>   REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/LWGT31294)**</kbd>.

**NOTA:** Yo he dado nombres más descriptivos a las columnas, para no perderme en el código y saber los datos que estoy tratando. Por eso los nombres de columna difieren de los tuyos. Eso lo puedes cambiar o dejarlo como lo tienes, a tu elección. De todos modos, conviene que el código sea lo más entendible posible, y usar nombres más descriptivos ayuda mucho.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega en el `WHERE` la condicion que relaciona las dos tablas users y matches:

```
SELECT u.*, m.* fROM users u, matches m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT idblock
FROM blocked b
WHERE b.idBlock = u.id AND b.idBlocked = 9) AND u.id <> 9 
      AND u.id = m.id
```

Comment: ¿Por qué relacionas `u.id = m.id` ?  La columna `id` de `matches` no parece ser otra cosa que un auto_increment que no tiene nada que ver con las relaciones. Precisamente creo que él no tiene claro cómo se debe relacionar `matches` con las demás tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano de hecho en la imagen que muestro se muestran dos id's que si, estas en lo correcto, son auto_increment, pero ambos son de tablas diferentes, el primero es de la tabla users y el segundo de la tabla match, obviamente ninnguno se relaciona entre si, los campos que se relacionan con el primer id (el de la tabla users) son el de idMatch y idMatched, como comento nebits si, la tabla de matches tiene una relacion de 1 a muchos, al igual que la tabla de blocked

Comment: Es que no entiendo @cesg.dav . O sea, la tabla `users` se relaciona con `matches` mediante `id` en `users` y ìdMatch` en `matches` ¿estamos de acuerdo hasta ahí?  Ahora bien, la columna `idMatched` con qué tabla se relaciona y mediante qué columna en esa tabla?

Comment: @A.Cedano todos los campos que tengan idAlgounDatos se relacionaran con el id de la tabla users colocare unas imagenes para que se muestre con claridad

Comment: En la última edición se entiende un poco más. Realmente las imágenes suelen servir de muy poco. Ayuda más la constitución de las tablas en si y un pequeño ejemplo de los datos que hay. Por lo que dices entonces las tablas sirven para expresar relaciones entre varios usuarios. Es un dato fundamental que no habias dicho hasta ahora. O sea quieres saber quién no ha bloqueado a quien. Eso cambia toda la perspectiva porque hay que hacer un doble JOIN en la tabla usuarios.