# Bases de datos relaciones

Tags: mysql, relaciones

esto de las bases de datos es nuevo para mi, he buscado con anterioridad mi consulta pero me lio con las respuestas por que las preguntas no son igual que la mia, quizas similares pero no logro relacionar las respuestas a mi pregunta, por lo que dejo mi consulta por aqui.

Estoy desarrollando un videojuego y me surge la necesidad de que cada usuario el cual contiene: Email, Nick,ID,Contraseña | quiero que estos usuario se relacionen entre si es decir amigos, pero puede existir que uno no sea amigo del otro ("Peticion de amistad"). Por lo que he pensado en crear dos listas de amigos(los que son amigos y los que te enviaron solicitud).

Por lo que me surge la siguiente duda, como creo una relación entre usuarios de la misma indole ?

Al crear un nuevo usuario se crea un nuevo registro en una tabla por lo que tendría que crear a la par otra tabla asociada a esta? o con las relaciones echas estas tablas se crean automáticamente ?

Espero haberme explicado con claridad.
Un saludo, y gracias de antemano.

Comment: necesitas otra tabla de relaciones.. donde hasta podrias poner un flag para saber la relacion es solo una peticion o una amistad real. tambien podria ser doble via.. puede que vos seas mi amigo, pero yo no tuyo. igual, este tema da para opiniones.

Comment: Alex, creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/180242/29967) describe lo que quieres... y mucho más. Si tienes alguna duda, escribe un comentario en la respuesta (para recibir notificación y ayudarte ante cualquier duda).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, tratare de comentar el resultado cuando lo tenga !